# EPEL's Centos 6 repo does have clang but doesn't have std lib to use it

Tags: c++, centos, clang, libstdc++, epel

I have just installed `clang` (3.4.2) from EPEL's Centos 6 repo (together with dependencies: `llvm` 3.4.2 and `llvm-libs` 3.4.2) but I have found out that there is no std lib to support it there.

Full list of packages [here](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/)

So when I try to compile c++11 programs I get error that link to gcc 4.4.6 which already resides on my machine.

Am I missing anything in here? I know that I can specify a std library to use (as described in here http://libcxx.llvm.org/) but I need one first :)

Comment: AFAIK, you need to build it yourself.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Which packages did you install?

Comment: @EtanReisner just as stated in the question: `clang` 3.4.2, `llvm` 3.4.2, `llvm-libs` 3.4.2